# Oracle SQL Loader - load file where record is composed of "n" delimiters

Tags: oracle, command-line, sql-loader, filestream

How would you write a control file for Oracle SQL Loader that treats each record as being composed of 3 commas?

I have read the documentation, however I cannot find how to handle this scenario, without having to edit my data file by hand.

For example, my data file has:

```
fd,3232,gfd67gf,
peas,989767,jkdfnfgjhf,
dhdhjsk,267,ujfdsy,fuyds,637296,ldosi,fduy,
873,fuisouyd,try
save,2837,ipoi
```

I would like to load the data into the table looking like this:

```
col1       col2       col3

fd         3232       gfd67gf
peas       989767     jkdfnfgjhf
dhdhjsk    267        ujfdsy
fuyds      637296     ldosi
fduy       873        fuisouyd
try\nsave  2837       ipoi
```

Note: Where I have "\n" in the last row of col1, I mean an actual line feed not literally "\n".

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't modify the input file? It's trivial to script a modification.

Comment: I thought SQLLoader could handle this sort of thing

Comment: Does this help:? [How does one load records with multi-line fields?](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#How_does_one_load_multi-line_records.3F)

Comment: The \n is doable with the link provided by @ypercube above. However, I can't find any way of dealing with multiple records on the same row in this situation. I could be wrong, but I've just spent 1/2 hour trying to massage them in & got nowhere.

Comment: Even with ypercube's link it shows no way of saying a record is formed of 3 commas

Answer (score 2):

So the linefeed before *peas* and *dhdhjsk* should be skipped but the linefeed before *save* is part of the data. Which linefeeds should be skipped and which are part of the data? I think such a format is very error prone and should be avoided. Perhaps you can do it the following way but I did not verify this

- define "," as the physical record separator
- join three physical records to on logical records
- to skip a leading *\n* trim leading whitespace from fields  or use sql-functions

The following links to the manual can provide information:

[Concatenating physical records to logical records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#i1011559)

[Input formats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#i1004677)

[Whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#autoId68)

[Apply SQL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#autoId75)

[Specifying delimiters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#i1007368)

Comment: I'd say it's not a valid answer if you haven't verified it.

Comment: @Phil Answers do not have to be verified to be accurate.  I think people asking questions would prefer an unverified answer over no answer at all.  Even if an answer turns out to be wrong it will at least provide a guidepost to what doesn't work.  Disclosing that the answer has not been verified is beneficial and allows the OP and voting system to verify the answer.  I haven't verified the answer either, but I voted for it because I believe it is headed in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I was just unsure, as it looks to be troublesome.